# Why is gimbal lock of euler angle a problem in non-linear optimization(SLAM, Simultaneously Localization And Mapping)

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, euler-angles, slam

I understand how the gimbal lock happens when using euler angle. However, I don't know why the gimbal lock is a problem in the SLAM(maybe in non-linear optimization). In the process of non-linear optimization, it seems that a problem occurs when doing non-linear optimization, seeing that parameterization is usually done with quaternions instead of euler angles. Why is gimbal lock of euler angle a problem in non-linear optimization?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.